# Problem on $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb Z_6,R^*\oplus C^*)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If  $\mathbb R^*$ and $\mathbb C^*$ be respectively multiplicative groups of non-zero real and complex number then whether $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb Z_6,R^*\oplus C^*)$  is  isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{12}$? or $\mathbb Z_6$? or $\mathbb Z_6\oplus \mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you thought about what elements of those multiplicative groups have finite order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $\mathbb{Z}/6 \cong \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/3$, for any group $G$ a homomorphism $f : \mathbb{Z}/6 \to G$ correspondents to a pair of homomorphisms $(g,h)$ with $g : \mathbb{Z}/2 \to G$ and $h : \mathbb{Z}/3 \to G$.